# Get data from json array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Hello please i am having trouble getting the data from the following array which was returned via ajax:

```
Array
(
    [routes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 4
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Soye
                    [to] => Martelange
                    [fare] => 98
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 9
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Auckland
                    [to] => Stevoort
                    [fare] => 65
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 11
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Bowden
                    [to] => Kessel
                    [fare] => 60
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 17
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Berg
                    [to] => Clearwater Municipal District
                    [fare] => 97
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 24
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Martelange
                    [to] => Soye
                    [fare] => 98
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 29
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Stevoort
                    [to] => Auckland
                    [fare] => 65
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 31
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Kessel
                    [to] => Bowden
                    [fare] => 60
                    [is_active] => 
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [route_id] => 37
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [from] => Clearwater Municipal District
                    [to] => Berg
                    [fare] => 97
                    [is_active] => 
                )

        )

)
```

This is my javascript:

```
var data = {id:id}; //Array

        $.ajax({
            url : url+"ticketinfo/routes",
            type: "POST",
            data : data,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                var jsonArray = data.routes;
                var options = $("#options");
                $.each(jsonArray , function(index, data) {
                    //adds all this values fron the array ,only from and to

                    options.append($("<option/>").text(data.from + " / " + data.from)); 
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

            }
        });
```

And by trouble i mean i do not know how, i have tried several examples here but none worked for me. What i want to do exactly is get these two fields in the array: from and to and use that data to dynamically populate two select controls dynamically with jquery. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out with this. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

So apparently it all had to do with the encoding and the decoding of the json array. The reason Csdtestings answer did not work was because the array he used in his example was not a json encoded object array i think.  Anyway i tried using json.parse on the returned  array which got rid of the error but then i had another problem which is the array elements all appeared as "[object][object]".  So then it occured to me that it might have something to do with the type of array that had been encoded. So i went back to my php and changed this:

```
$data = $this->route->get_routes_by_company($company_id); //using codeigniter framework
echo json_encode($data);
```

To this:

```
$data = $this->route->get_routes_by_company($company_id); //using codeigniter framework
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $result = array($row['from'], $row['to']);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

after which i just changed my javascript to this and voila it worked:

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: url+"ticketinfo/routes",
    data: {
        'id' : id
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
       if (response.length > 0)
       {
          $.each(response, function(index, element) {
               $('#From').append("<option value='" + element[0] + "'>" + element[0] + "</option>");
               $('#To').append("<option value='" + element[1] + "'>" + element[1] + "</option>");           
          });
       }
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it, have you tried the following method below to check the output to your console as a test result?

```
var routes = data.routes
for(var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++){
    console.log(routes[i].to);
    console.log(routes[i].from);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: routes is undefined
for(var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++){

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var selectData1 = "";
var selectData2 = "";
routes.each(function(index,options)
{
  selectData1 += '<option>' + $(this)[0].from + '</option>';
  selectData2 += '<option>' + $(this)[0].to + '</option>';

});

  $("#select1ID").html(selectData1);
  $("#select2ID").html(selectData2);
```

I haven't tried it so do expect some syntax error, but this should do the job you need.